# HTML tbody height setting when displayed content is less

Tags: html

If TBODY height is 300px and the displayed content inside it will be only 50px, it shows empty space at the bottom of the content as from 51PX to 300PX, My intension is If content > 300 using overflow:auto I want to display scrollbar. Please suggest me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


div.TableContainerToScroll  {
            height: 651px;
            overflow: auto;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 15px 0 0 0;
            position: relative;
            vertical-align:top;
        }

html>/**/body div.TableContainerToScroll table>tbody {
            overflow: auto;
            height: 200px;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            background-color: #00FF00;
        }

div.otherclass  {}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pdata" class="TableContainerToScroll">
<div class="otherclass">
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="97%" align=center border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=center border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>
<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 width="100%" align=center border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD align=center><BR>Sample Text Here<BR></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>  </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Post the html/css you have so far and we will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that rows are at least as tall as the content. See [Table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout):

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user
>   agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the
>   row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the
>   row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells.

And [`max-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#min-max-heights) won't help, because

> In CSS 2.1, the effect of 'min-height' and 'max-height' on tables,
>   inline tables, table cells, table rows, and row groups is undefined.

Then, you can't make the contents overflow the cells. However, you can wrap the contents in a container with `max-height`, and let it overflow:

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 175px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid;
}
p.tall {
  height: 400px;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p class="tall">I am so tall</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <p>I am not tall</p>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Orio, My issue is not resolved, In my form By default for all tbody elements in a DIV tag, the default height is 300 px, In any one of the TBODY tag If the content of it's TD tags is less than 300px, how can I eliminate empty space at bottom, max-height is not useful here,

Comment: @Prabha Then, if the content is taller than 300px you want the cell to be 300px tall with overflow, and otherwise you want the cell to be as tall as the content? In that case use `max-height: 300px` on the wrapper, and `height: auto` on the table, row, cell and wrapper.

Comment: I understand your point,In my code multiple TBODY tags exists in multiple DIV's, here all DIVs are included in one ParenDIV, this parentDiv sets TBODY height to 300px, most of TBODY's in child DIVs don't need 300px height as these contains single line text only, I can't put individual heights separately on each TBODY as this form included more than 40 DIVs. Same time I can't restrict the parent inherit access of TBODY property to specific child DIV, even If I do this(by providing TBODY style in child DIV where issue resides currently) I don't know when the content grows> 300 by nexttime

Comment: @Prabha Please include the code in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi Oriol, run the above code in browser in IE compatibility mode the style (height: 200px;) mentioned in TableContainerToScroll table>tbody is not applied to text "sample text here" which is in inner DIV(which uses otherclass) , here parentDIV(pdata) uses TableContainerToScroll class, other than IE compatibility mode, In standard IE10, IE11, chrome, Mozilla .....browsers inherits the outer DIV tbody style to inner DIV and shows empty space at the bottom of the "sample text here" content. Please check the attached code snippet.

Comment: @Prabha That's because `.TableContainerToScroll table` selects all tables inside `.TableContainerToScroll`. Try `.TableContainerToScroll > .otherclass > table > tbody` instead. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/baj45u6n/)

Comment: Oriol, thank you, I tried as you mentioned, current issue has been resolved & the other issue is expression(this.offsetparent.scrolltop) not working in IE11 to make <thead> element not scrollable, In my local style applied to thead as      --------------div.scrollTableContainer thead tr {
    position:relative;
    top: expression(offsetParent.scrollTop); 
    left: 0px;
   }

Comment: @Prabha That is invalid CSS. Don't use it.

Comment: What's the alternate css I can use